# Dojo: dojo/text & CORS

Tags: javascript, dojo, cors

I'm using dojo version 1.9.1 and trying to access the widgets I have created from other domain  from where they reside. I'm getting the

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource"

for everything that is trying to be loaded via dojo/text!, so basically to all my templates. I reckon interning them using the build should be just fine, but other resources will fail as well.

searching using google pointed me to dojo bug tracking and interestingly, it was fixed in 1.8 but since the dojo/text has changed the object from xhr to request, it became an issue again.
There used to be a parameter for dojoConfig -> textPluginHeaders that was supposed to resolve this.

But even when I create my own custom/text! object using the previous version of dojo/text, I fail miserably at retrieving the cross-domain resources.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't provide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your other domain?

Comment: I don't have an access to that domain except deploying to it.

Comment: Try to update to latest dojo framework it should solve your issue

Answer (score 2):

According to [ticket 17943](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17493) in their bug tracker, this issue was fixed as of Dojo 1.9.4. Have you tried upgrading the framework?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality provided by `textPluginHeaders` was never documented publicly, and as such, was never restored after `dojo/text` was changed to use `dojo/request` instead of `dojo/xhr`. As such, `X-Requested-With` will just not be sent with dojo/text requests.

See [Issue #17493](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17493#comment:3).